# Flutter http authenticator service to refresh oauth2 token

Tags: http, authentication, flutter, oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I am working on oauth2 authentication in a flutter app. I am thinking of refreshing the token when 401 authentication error happens in any of my API's. So how to add an authenticator service to all the http requests in flutter. In android we have okhttp authenticator to detect the authentication error during any API call and can refresh the token and proceed the previous API call. In flutter how to implement this? I dont think it is a good practice to handle 401 error in all the API's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dio interceptor

Below is a snippet from my interceptor

```
 dio.interceptors
        .add(InterceptorsWrapper(onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {

/* Write your request logic setting your Authorization header from prefs*/

      String token = await prefs.accessToken;
      if (token != null) {
        options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
      return options; //continue
    }, onResponse: (Response response) async {
// Write your response logic

      return response; // continue
    }, onError: (DioError dioError) async {

      // Refresh Token
      if (dioError.response?.statusCode == 401) {
        Response response;
        var data = <String, dynamic>{
          "grant_type": "refresh_token",
          "refresh_token": await prefs.refreshToken,
          'email': await prefs.userEmail
        };
        response = await dio
            .post("api/url/for/refresh/token", data: data);
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          var newRefreshToken = response.data["data"]["refresh_token"]; // get new refresh token from response
          var newAccessToken = response.data["data"]["access_token"]; // get new access token from response
          prefs.refreshToken = newRefreshToken;
          prefs.accessToken = newAccessToken; // to be used in the request section of the interceptor
          return dio.request(dioError.request.baseUrl + dioError.request.path,
              options: dioError.request);
        }
      }
      return dioError;
    }));
    return dio;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the pattern of parameterizing all API calls on the client side, as in [this code snippet](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/api/client/ApiClient.kt). This approach should work in any technology, though in some techs you may have options to implement it via some kind of interceptor class.

Comment: Yea i am expecting the same behaviour in flutter. I think dio package do the same functionality